# Functions Agreeing on Zariski Dense Sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

Let $X$ be an affine variety and $U\subset X$ Zariski open, Then, $U$ is dense in $X$ (i.e., the smallest set containing $U$ which is also the zero locus of a set of polynomials is $X$). Let $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ be continuous and agreeing on $U$.

Does it follow that $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ agree on $X$?

I'm trying to build intuition about how Zariski density is related to Euclidean density w.r.t. mappings.

Comment: Here are some things to clarify: are $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ are morphisms to some other scheme (this includes the case of regular functions, as a regular function is a morphism to $\Bbb A^1$)? If so, assuming $X$ is reduced and the target is separated, the answer is yes ([as has been covered here before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128060/proof-of-the-reduced-to-separated-theorem)). If $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ are just continuous functions to some other topological space, the answer is no: $\Bbb A^1$ has the cofinite topology, so a map which swaps two closed points is continuous.